# Once in SICStus Prolog?

Tags: prolog, syntax-error, iso-prolog

How can I use `once` in SICStus? 
In SWI Prolog, the following works:

```
test(X, Y, abc) :- once(X == 'true' ; Y == 'true').
```

but in SICStus Prolog, `once` seems to be unrecognized. What is the equivalent of `once` in SICStus?
Thank you.

Comment: Note that SWI is wrong here: The standard requires a syntax error in this case. SWI is the only system that accepts this malformed term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:

```
test(X, Y, abc) :- once((X == 'true' ; Y == 'true')).
```

The additional parenthesis did the trick.